# Go: array out of index panic error

Tags: arrays, sorting, indexing, go

I am implementing sorting but keep getting the index bound error in Go language.

My code is following

```
 func My_Partition(container []int, first_index int, last_index int) int {
      var x int = container[last_index]
      i := first_index - 1

      for j := first_index; i < last_index; j++ {
           if container[j] <= x {
                i += 1
                my_Swap(&container[i], &container[j])
           }
      }
      my_Swap(&container[i+1], &container[last_index])
      return i+1
 }
```

I am getting error in the line "if container[j] <= x" that says panic: runtime error: index out of range

```
    main.My_Partition(0x2101b20c0, 0x7, 0x7, 0x0, 0x6, ...)
/Path/main.go:34 +0xff
```

Anybody has an idea?

my swap function is below

```
 func my_Swap(a *int, b *int) {
      temp := *a
      *a = *b
      *b = temp
 }
```

but I don't think swap is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
for j := first_index; i < last_index; j++ {
```

Should be:

```
for j := first_index; j < last_index; j++ {
```

Easy enough mistake to make :-)

[Playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/t01_OPYP0N)

Comment: Thank you so much. That was a stupid mistake and couldn't figure out for three hours.... Thank you!

Comment: @dfsadxsadqwd213 no problem, I've done similar things many times! For future reference you don't need a custom swap function. Go supports multiple assignment so you can just do `container[i], container[j] = container[j], container[i]` with no need for temporary variables.

Comment: That's nice. I was coding in C mindset. I should have tried that like in Ruby and Python. Thanks

Comment: I made a similar mistake years ago, now I try to avoid using single letter variables whenever I can. The extra typing is a small price to pay for not having these bugs.